# I am fetching data using spark and collecting it in a delta lake

Tags: database, apache-spark, azure-data-lake, delta-lake

Now, I am running a job every day that fetches the data from delta lake of last 7 days, as the data contains the timestamp column. I am processing this data and writing to other database. As there is possibility of late data, I run this job every day and check for new data in last 7 day. But when I do so, I also get the old data with the new data. Hence the processing now I do, is for (rewriting(old data) + late data + new data). How can I stop processing the old data.Any Ideas?

Comment: what kind of the data processing happens?

Comment: @AlexOtt I am writing data to a postgres table, and every time I read data from lake of last 7 days , if its late data I overwrite it ( in this case I also overwrite data if its old), if not I insert it to new row.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do that is to [consume data from Delta table as a stream](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-streaming.html#id4) instead of reading data as a batch. In this case, stream will contain only data written into Delta table since the previous invocation. After you read your data, you can use [foreachBatch function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch) to write that data into your database.

Something like this (more a pseudo-code than real code):

```py
def my_foreach_batch(df, epoch):
  .... write df into database

df = spark.readStream.option("startingVersion", "<latest_consumed_version>") \
  .format("delta").load("delta_path")
df.writeStream.option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint_path") \
  .trigger(once=True).foreachBatch(my_foreach_batch).save()
```

Here are:

- `<latest_consumed_version>` - last Delta version you used before switching to streaming. You can also use `startingTimestamp` instead (see [docs](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-streaming.html#id4))
- `checkpoint_path` - path on HDFS/S3/... that will store information about versions processed by stream, so it will know where to start next time
- `trigger(once=True)` - defines that stream should start, process all available data at once, and stop. Alternatively you can use `trigger(availableNow=True)` that is available since Spark 3.3 - it will put less pressure on the nodes when processing data.